# Scraping multiple websites of different domains using python scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to scrape two different websites' emails with their corresponding links, but I get two different emails with the same link. Actually there are vaious websites to scrape, but for simplicity, I have used only two urls. The code is given below:

```
import scrapy
import re
import time
urls = ['http://www.manorhouseohio.com', 'http://www.OtterCreekAL.com']
class TheknotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'theknot'
    def start_requests(self):
        global url
        li = ['http://www.manorhouseohio.com','http://www.OtterCreekAL.com']
        for url in range(len(li)):
            yield scrapy.Request(li[url], callback=self.parse)
    def parse(self, response):
        mail_link = response.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'mailto:')]/@href").get()
        html_text = response.xpath("//body").get()
        mail_without_link = re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", html_text)
        contact = response.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/contact')]/@href").get()
        if mail_link:
            x = mail_link[7:]
            yield {
            "Main Website": urls[url],
            "Email": x
            }
            time.sleep(1)
        elif mail_without_link:
            yield {
            "Main Website": urls[url],
            "Email": mail_without_link
            }
            time.sleep(1)
        elif contact:
                if contact=="/contact" or contact=="/contact/" or contact=="/contact-us" or contact=="/contact-us/":
                    contact_main = urls[url] + contact
                    yield scrapy.Request(contact_main, callback=self.parse_final)       
                else:
                    yield scrapy.Request(contact, callback=self.parse_final)
        else:
            pass
    def parse_final(self, response):
        mail = response.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'mailto:')]/@href").get()
        text = response.xpath("//body").get()
        mail_text = re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", text)
        if mail:
            x = mail[7:]
            yield {
            "Main Website": urls[url],
            "Email": x
            }
            time.sleep(1)
        elif mail_text:
            yield {
            "Main Website": urls[url],
            "Email": mail_text
            }
            time.sleep(1)
        else: pass
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, I have to scrape multiple different websites' emails alongwith urls. In the above example, I have shown just 2 websites (of different domains) for simplicity. The problem is that, (it scrapes emails well but) their corresponding links are not correct. So, in the above example, 2 different emails are scraped with same website link.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but your comment still doesn’t include a question, you are just stating your problem. Please try to be as specific as possible so people can help you [ask]

Comment: The above example shows the result in json format like this:
[
{"Main Website": "http://www.OtterCreekAL.com", "Email": "info@manorhouseohio.com"},
{"Main Website": "http://www.OtterCreekAL.com", "Email": "reservations@ottercreekal.com"}
]
Here, the 1st link isn't correct, it should be "http://www.manorhouseohio.com".

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that `scrapy` does not execute synchronously. This means that your `global` `url` variable is not what you think it is. `start_requests` will (likely) fully execute before any parse functions are called and so `url` will be 1 inside all your `parse` methods.

Rather than using the global variables, access the url of the response with `response.url` and if you need the base url then use [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) (or similar) to get it.

Comment: Yea, now it worked when I added the 3rd argument in each request i.e. 
yield scrapy.Request(urls[url], callback=self.parse,cb_kwargs=dict(url=url))

Anyway, Thank you, Mr. @tomjn